# Allow open access to the home page of CakePhp with nonstatic elements

Tags: php, cakephp

I have want to allow open access to the home page of a CakePhp site that has two nonstatic elements(both containing a list from the DB).

Currently non logged in users get redirected to the login page because of these elements. 
How can I set it up so that non logged in users can see the home page and still view the nonstatic elements?

Thanks for any help you can provide,

kSeudo

Comment: Uhm... Allow the corresponding controller action to be accessed by anybody? This all depends on your configuration of the Auth component, or however else you're handling logins, it has nothing to do with static or dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain how do you redirect to the login page?

I suppose that you do it on AppController::beforeFilter, so I think that you can try to override that method on your controler.

I mean:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

   function beforeFilter() {
     //Check if user is logged or not and then redirect
   }
}

class PagesController extends Controller {
   function beforeFilter() { //Override method, don't use AppController

   }
}
```